# Prove using the formal definition of a limit that

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How would I go about proving this limit?

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5}=0$

so far I have:

$|f(x) -L|< ϵ$ wherever $x > N$

$|\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5} - 0| < ϵ $ wherever $x > N$

$|\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5}| < ϵ  ,\; x > ∞$, assuming, $x > 0$

taking the absolute value $\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5} < ϵ$

${x^4+x^2+5}$ > $\frac{1}{ϵ}$

i am not sure whether this is correct, but what would be the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $x^4+x^2+5 > x^4 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x^4+x^2+5} < \dfrac{1}{x^4}$. Thus you need $\dfrac{1}{x^4} < \epsilon \Rightarrow x^4 > \epsilon^{-1} \Rightarrow x > \epsilon^{-\frac{1}{4}}$. This means for a given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ a natural number such that $N \geq 1+ \epsilon^{-\frac{1}{4}}$, then whenever $x > N \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. Where does the 'e' come from?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1}{x^4+x^2+5}\le \frac{1}{x^4}<\epsilon$$

whenever $x>B=\epsilon^{-1/4}$.